# Getting error `object has no attribute LAYER_ID_COUNT' in KiCad PCBNEW trying to add track in Python script

Tags: kicad

I am trying to programatically add a new track to a KiCad board using the Python API. My code fails when trying to assign the layer to the new track.

My code is modeled off this example...

https://github.com/mmccoo/kicad_mmccoo/blob/master/basics/basics.py#L141

...which builds a dictionary of available layers, and then uses that dictionary to look up the desired layer by name.

Unfortunately the field `pcbnew.LAYER_ID_COUNT` doe snot seem to exist in the latest version of KiCad (5.1.2). To confirm, I typed the following into the Python command prompt...

```
import pcbnew
pcbnew.LAYER_ID_COUNT
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LAYER_ID_COUNT'
```

How can I work around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The following code will create the `layertable` table used by the above example (and many other examples)...

```
layertable = {}

for i in range(1000):
    name = board.GetLayerName(i)
    if name != "BAD INDEX!":
        layertable[name]=i
```

It is a horrible hack, but it works. It makes the reasonable assumption that there will never be more than 1000 layers.

Once the above code as set up the `layertable` dictionary, you can assign a layer to a track like this...

```
track.SetLayer(layertable["F.Cu"])
```